# QGIS Plugin in a web server

Tags: geoserver, qgis-plugins

Is it possible to access a qgis plugin through a web-server ? As an example, say Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. I want the plugin to be accessed through a server (preferably GeoServer). I've migrated all the input files to a PostGres database. I would like to run few process through the plugin which should be accessible through web-portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that exact case the answer is almost certainly no, a QGIS plugin will not run inside GeoServer as one is in C or python and the other is Java.

If you need to run a process on a remote server then look at GeoServer's [Web Processing Server](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/index.html) extension which allows you to add Java processes to GeoServer.

As far as I know QGIS server does not support WPS services. But other python based WPS Servers do exist such as [Zoo WPS](https://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/zoo-project_overview.html) and [PyWPS](https://live.osgeo.org/archive/en/overview/pywps_overview.html) but I doubt that they can handle a QGIS pluygin with out a fair amount of work.